# How to set custom headers for HTTP::Tiny in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm having some trouble understanding the proper way to set headers for `HTTP::Tiny` in Perl 5. So far I have seen examples of hashes, hash references, and a myriad of other seemingly incomposable ways.

What is the proper way of setting the headers for a request? What's an easy way to view the request before it is sent?

Here is some example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                                                                                                                             
use 5.12.1;                                                                                                                                                                                     
use HTTP::Tiny;                                                                                                                                                                                 

my $api_key = "::";                                                                                                                                                                             

my %headers = (Authorization => sprintf 'Bearer %s', $api_key);                                                                                                                                            
my $url = "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts";                                                                                                                                          

my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new($url, 
   default_headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'});                                                              

my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get($url, { default_headers => \%headers } );                                                                                                                    

print "$response->{status} $response->{reason}\n";                                                                                                                                                                                                
while ( my ( $k, $v ) = each %{ $response->{headers} } ) { 
        print "$k: $_\n";   
    }                                                                                                                                                                                           
}

print $response->{content} if length $response->{content};
```

And it is giving me a 401.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

hash means just `%hash=(key=>value)`

hash references means just `$hashref={key=>value}` and this equal to `$hashref=\%hash;`

So

`$http = HTTP::Tiny->new( %attributes )` is just

`$http = HTTP::Tiny->new( attr1=>value1, ... )`

And

`$response = $http->get($url, \%options)` is

`$response = $http->get($url, {attr1=>value1, ...} )`

illustrative examples:

```
use HTTP::Tiny;
HTTP::Tiny->new->get($url);
HTTP::Tiny->new->get($url, { headers => { header1=>value1, header2=>value2 } };

# with headers set in one place
$handle=HTTP::Tiny->new( default_headers=>{h1=>3, h2=>4} );
$handle->get($url);
$handle->get($url, headers=>{ h2=>'overwrite' });

# without shorthand
HTTP::Tiny->new->request('GET', $url);
HTTP::Tiny->new->request('GET',$url, { headers => { header1=>value1, header2=>value2 } };

# post
HTTP::Tiny->new->request('POST',$url, { headers => { header1=>value1, header2=>value2 }, content=>'body to post' };
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem had a lot to do with me being stupid and not paying attention to the details. Basically,

1. I was using the real money api, not the fake one
2. I was not using a hashref properly
3. I was setting 'default_headers' instead of 'headers'

`

```
my $api_key = "::"

my %headers = (
    "Content-Type" => "application/json",
    "Authorization" => sprintf 'Bearer %s', $api_key);

my $url = "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/accounts";

my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get($url, { headers => \%headers } );

print "$response->{status} $response->{reason}\n";

while ( my ( $k, $v ) = each %{ $response->{headers} } ) {
    for ( ref $v eq 'ARRAY' ? @$v : $v ) {
        print "$k: $_\n";
    }
}

print $response->{content} if length $response->{content};
```

`